# Mean minimum distance of a random walk for a certain number of steps to a given point in space

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Given there is a 3D random walk starting at the origin $\vec{0}$. For simplicity, lets assume a lattice, where the walker randomly goes exactly one unit per step in one of the coordinate directions. This means after one step the walker is at one of the six positions $(0,0,1)$, $(0,0,-1)$,...,$(-1,0,0)$ with a probability of $1/6$.

The question is: For an arbitrary point on the lattice $\vec{p}$, what is the expected minimum distance of the walker to this specific point, given the random walk consists of $N$ steps.

More formally, let $\vec{r}(n)$ be the position of the walker at step n. The distance between walker and $p$ for each step is $d(n) = \sqrt{(\vec{r}(n)-\vec{p})^2}$.

What is the expected minimum distance $\left<d_{min}\right> = \left<\min\limits_{n = 0,\dots, N}d(n)\right>$?

---

Until now, I haven't found the solution for this in the literature. The problem is that I don't really know what to look for. Is there an established name for this problem? I assume that the solution is relevant when looking at the dynamics of diffusive processes. For example: I have a molecule with a certain diffusion coefficient. What is the probability that it is within 1 nm of my target site given a certain amount of time?

Comment: Have a look at [this forum post answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3471115) where the expected distance of a random walk to the origin is calculated. In the given answer, you can replace the random walk position vector $\vec R$ with $\vec R -\vec p$ in order to calculate the mean distance of $\vec R$ to the point $\vec p$. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure if the solution for the RMS transfers to my question, because I'm looking for the expected minimum distance. This should be a monotonically decreasing function with respect to N. I don't see how to derive this from the answer that is outlined there. In other words, I don't see how the minimum distance, which depends on each individual trajectory, can be derived from the ensemble average.

Comment: As it is random seems plausible to me that the average distance is going to be the same as the distance with $0$ "steps".

Comment: This is certainly true for an unbiased random walker, but the average minimum distance is monotonically decreasing. 
A very quick simulation of this problem in 1D does not look like a power-law behavior.