# Reference Request, Random Walk

Tags: reference-request, random-walk

The expected distance from origin after a random walk of $N$ steps in a $d$ dimensional space, is close to $$\sqrt{\dfrac{2N}{d}}\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{d+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{d}{2}\right)}$$ for very large $N$. This was mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103170/39599). I would be very obliged if someone can mention to me a reference (bibliographic) to an article, book or any publication, where this expression was derived or mentioned. Please restrict to references, and not explanation of the formula itself.

Comment: The expression was given by "Henry" to a question by "Diego" in january 2012. Is it possible to have the source of this Formula?

Comment: You might try to [ping](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/comment-replies/info) Henry under his answer, to see, whether he knows about a reference.

Comment: @ Martin Sleziak, thanks a lot. Unfortunately I am not qualified to add a comment to the old answer. Do you have an idea how can I contact Henry on the subject. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For those seeking for the reference > 4 years after the question was asked, here is a 2011 paper with explicit computations: 
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8e6b/03f71b0bd3e38b50dde5f6a36a9a7ae91183.pdf