# Central limit Theorem (Random Walker Problem)

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems

A walker is at point zero on a straight line. The walker goes each time step $\Delta t =  1$, either one step to left (-1) or one step to right (+1), both having the probability of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Using CLT, what would be the average distance from zero after taking N steps? (N is very large.)

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: a random variable taking the values $\pm1$ each with probability $\frac12$ has mean $0$ and variance $1$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103142/expected-value-of-random-walk